# Stop a function that contains jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to stop the execution of the function PadanjeFun when `ZivotBroj==-5`.

I tried jQuery `stop()` Method, `clearInterval(myVar)` and return but it's not working.

I need to stop all tree animation (`#cepJedan, #cepDva, #cepTri`) when `ZivotBroj==-5`

Here is the code:

```
var PadanjeFun=function(){

if(bod==4) //Change speed when bod reaches the number
{
    q=4;
}
else if(bod==7)
{
    q=3;
}


$(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval(function(){ //Neka zakasni prvi cep
        $("#cepJedan").animate({
            top: "850px",
        },1000 * q, function(){
            BodRacunaj();
            document.getElementById("cepJedan").style.top = "150px";
            ZivotOduzmi();
            document.getElementById("Broj").innerHTML = bod; 
        });

        }, 1000); //Let it start after 1 sec
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){

        setInterval(function(){
            $("#cepDva").animate({
                top: "850px",
            },1000 * q, function(){
                BodRacunaj();
                document.getElementById("cepDva").style.top = "150px";
                ZivotOduzmi();
                document.getElementById("Broj").innerHTML = bod;
            });

        }, 9000); //Let it start after 9 sec
      });

    $(document).ready(function(){

        setInterval(function(){
            $("#cepTri").animate({
                top: "850px",
            },1000 * q, function(){
                BodRacunaj();
                document.getElementById("cepTri").style.top = "150px";
                ZivotOduzmi();
                PadanjeFun();
                console.log("Q je: "+q);
                document.getElementById("Broj").innerHTML = bod;
            });

        }, 3000); //Let it start after 3 sec
      });


}
```

Here is the ZivotOduzmi function if that helps anyone:

```
var ZivotOduzmi=function(){
if((document.getElementById("cepJedan").style.top == "850px") && (document.getElementById("box").style.left == "550px") || (document.getElementById("box").style.left == "980px"))
    {
    zivotBroj--;
    console.log("Imate jos ovoliko zivota: "+zivotBroj);

    var element = document.getElementById('Zivot'); 
    element.style.width = (element.offsetWidth - 100) + 'px'; 

    }
else if((document.getElementById("cepDva").style.top == "850px") && (document.getElementById("box").style.left == "120px") || (document.getElementById("box").style.left == "980px"))
    {
    zivotBroj--;
    console.log("Imate jos ovoliko zivota: "+zivot);

    var element = document.getElementById('Zivot'); 
    element.style.width = (element.offsetWidth - 100) + 'px'; 

    }
else if((document.getElementById("cepTri").style.top == "850px") && (document.getElementById("box").style.left == "120px") || (document.getElementById("box").style.left == "550px") )
    {
    zivotBroj--;
    console.log("Imate jos ovoliko zivota: "+zivotBroj);

    var element = document.getElementById('Zivot'); 
    element.style.width = (element.offsetWidth - 100) + 'px'; 

    }
}
```

Comment: you can use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign setInterval to a variable like:

```
var anim3;
$(document).ready(function(){

    anim3 = setInterval(function(){
        $("#cepDva").animate({
            top: "850px",
        },1000 * q, function(){
            BodRacunaj();
            document.getElementById("cepDva").style.top = "150px";
            ZivotOduzmi();
            document.getElementById("Broj").innerHTML = bod;
        });

    }, 9000); //Let it start after 9 sec
  });
```

and call

```
clearInterval(anim3);
$("#cepDva").stop();
```

Comment: Tried that, added krajigre like you did anim3, and I added.
`if(zivotBroj==-2)
  {
  clearInterval(krajigre);
  $("#cepJedan").stop();
  }`
Still animates for some reason.